# When using the Mongo C# driver, does query sorting occur within Mongo, or at the C# level?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose you want to retrieve a bunch of documents that have a timestamp field from a Mongo database using the C# driver, and you want them sorted by timestamp in decreasing order (-1).

When creating an index, do you need to include the timestamp field in the -1 order, for the queries that sort this way?  Or is it unnecessary because sorting will only occur once the documents have been extracted from the Mongodb and converted to C# objects, and thus sorted "in-memory" by .NET?

Suppose my documents have the fields:
user_id,
action_id, and
timestamp

I want to have an index that will aid the search for all actions for a user, and sorted in decreasing order.  Should my index include just user_id and action_id, or should it also use the timestamp field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Accodring to the docs](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/crud/linq/), the Mongo driver contains a LINQ implementation targeting the Mongo aggregation framework. That means a query like

```
var query = from p in collection.AsQueryable()
            orderby p.Name, p.Age descending
            select p;

//or

var query = collection.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.Age);
```

would map into the following aggregation pipeline:

```
[
    { $sort: { Name: 1, Age: -1 } },
]
```

Of course you don't have to use LINQ, you can also write equivalent queries without it. But the answer is that yes, the driver does support converting your queries into something executed on the DB side.

[This page in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-with-a-single-field-index) refers I believe to the exact situation you're describing:

```
db.records.createIndex( { a: 1 } )
```

would support both in-order and reverse-order traversal:

```
db.records.find().sort( { a: 1 } )
db.records.find().sort( { a: -1 } )
```

The docs have plenty of information on indexes so I recommend you read up on them to get a feeling of what's best for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB is capable of sorting the data before sending it back to the client. When you provide a `sort` clause on a query, it is the `mongod` that is actually performing the sort, not the driver or the .NET runtime.

For sorting, there are 2 things that can happen, depending on the indexes available:

1. Sort using the index
2. Sort without an index

A good rule of thumb is, if you want to sort on a field, the index created for that query needs to *end* with that field.

So if you are querying on *just* the `timestamp` field, then you only need an index of `timestamp: -1` or `timestamp: 1`. The index can be used for queries with either sort direction.

If you are querying on multiple fields, then you want the index to end with `timestamp`. So for the example you provided, you might want an index like `{ user_id: 1, action_id: 1, timestamp: -1 }`, which would support that exact query.

If an index does not exist that can be used for sorting, it will happen in memory. However, there is a limitation on in-memory sorts, to prevent degradation of service. As of writing this, [it is 32 MB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#restrictions). If the sort operation requires more than that, you need to create an index.

Comment: Good insight on the in-memory restriction, I did not know that. I wish multiple answers could be marked as accepted since yours definitely deserves it at least as much as mine.

Comment: @DanielCrha c'est la vie. As long as the information gets out there!